# Suppose $G$ be a finite group, $a \in G$ has finite order, then check whether the formula true or false?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

***Suppose $G$ be a finite group, $a \in G$ has finite order, then check whether the formula true or false? $ \langle a^m\rangle \cap\langle a^n\rangle=\langle a^{lcm(m,n)mod|a|}\rangle$***

My attempt to prove the result,

***Proof***.  Let $x \in \langle a^{lcm(m,n)mod|a|}\rangle.$

We know that $m|lcm(m,n)$ and $n|lcm(m,n).$

$•••$

How to to proceed further to obtain $x \in \langle a^m\rangle$ and $x \in\langle a^n\rangle$

Conversely,

$x \in \langle a^m\rangle\cap\langle a^n\rangle$

$x \in \langle a^m\rangle$ and $x \in\langle a^n\rangle $

$x=a^{ms}$ and $x=a^{nt},$ where $s,t \in \mathbb{Z} $

$•••$

How to proceed further to prove $x \in \langle a^{lcm(m,n)mod|a|}\rangle$

Please provide hints to complete the proof.
Is this formula false? I am not able to find the counter examples. If this formula false,  what are the extra conditions required to make it correct?

Comment: What is $mod(|a|)?$

Comment: |a| represents the order of the element a.